# Ubuntu 12.10 installation hang on console screen : "Output LVDS-1 is running on CRTC 1 using output A"

Tags: installation, 12.10, laptop, 32-bit

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 (32 bits) on a (rather old) [HP Pavilion zd7010CA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269340/ubuntu-12-10-installation-hang-on-console-screen-output-lvds-1-is-running-on) laptop. I'm running the install so it replace everything on the laptop.

Everything went fine, I passed the various installations screen until I got the "Learn more about Ubuntu while the system installs…", But I did not get the "Installation complete" screen, instead, I got this :

[image: screen photo]

The mouse pointer is there and move with the mouse, but nothing else.

---

After my failed attempt to install Ubuntu 12.10, I decided to try to install Ubuntu 12.04.2 (32 bits) instead.

But after only 2 screen, (selection of the language an the one you could select "download update while installing" the installation hang on this console screen.

[image: screen photo]

Again, the mouse pointer is there and move with the mouse, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run the installation of Ubuntu 12.04.2 Selection `English` instead of `French` and everything went fine.